# Find the minimum value of $T=a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2$

Tags: inequality, optimization, systems-of-equations, maxima-minima

Given reals $a,b,c,d$ such that $$\left\{\begin{matrix}(a+b)(c+d)=2 
 &  & \\(a+c)(b+d)=3
 &  & \\ (a+d)(b+c)=4
 &  & 
\end{matrix}\right..$$
Find the minimum value of  $  T=a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2.$

I noticed that $(a+b)(c+d)+(a+c)(b+d)+(a+d)(b+c)=2ab+2ac+2ad+2bc+2bd+2cd\leq 3(a^2+b^2+c^2)=3T$

by applying the inequality $x^2+y^2\geq2xy$ $\forall x,y\in \mathbb R$. So $T\geq 3$ . However, equality doesn't occur with this method.

Could you help me solve the problem?

> The answer is 7.

Comment: In fact, we have $  2(a^2 + d^2) + 2 (b^2 + c)^2 \geq (a+d)^2 + (b+c)^2 \geq 2(a+d)(b+c)$, so $ T \geq 4$ is a greater lower bound. However, this still cannot be achieved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By your work and by AM-GM we obtain:
$$a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=(a+b+c+d)^2-2-3-4\geq4(a+d)(b+c)-9=7.$$
The equality occurs for example, for $a+d=b+c=2$,

which gives that the equality indeed occurs:
$$d=2-a,$$ $$c=2-b,$$
$$(a+b)(4-a-b)=2$$ and
$$(a-b+2)(b-a+2)=3.$$
Can you end it now?

Comment: (comment was made during your edit) You'd actually still have to verify that equality can be achieved, and satisfy the other conditions. It can with $ a = - \frac{1}{ \sqrt{2} }$, $ b = 1 - \frac{1}{ \sqrt{2}}$, $c = 1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, $ d = 2 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.